# Spring Data JPA nested SELECT on update statement not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sql-update, jpql

I have those models:

```
@Entity
public class Payment {
    ...
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Colum(name = "amount_received")
    private Integer amountReceived;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "payment", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = LAZY )
    private Set<Cart> Carts;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
   ...
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "payment_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
    private Payment payment;

    @Column( name="product_id"
    private String productID; 
}
```

I would like to update `Payment.amountReceived` knowing `Cart.productID` so I defined this method on `PaymentRepository`:

```
@Modifying
@Query( value = "update payment pay set pay.amount_received = pay.amount_received + ?2 where pay.id = (select p.id from cart c inner join payment p on c.payment_id = p.id where c.product_id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true )
int updateAmountReceived( String idProduct, int amount );
```

But the update is never done and no exception is thrown.

I tried the same request on JPQL:

```
@Modifying
@Query( value = "update Payment pay set pay.amountReceived = pay.amountReceived + ?2 where pay.id in (select c.payment.id from Cart c where c.productID = ?1)")
int updateAmountReceived( String idProduct, int amount );
```

But same result. 
Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried the native SQL in the SQL console? Did it work?

Comment: @KonstantinTriger Yes it works fine in SQL console.

Comment: It means that you have a problem elsewhere. When you call updateAmountReceived, what does it return?

Comment: @JensSchauder There is any exception but I found the answer on the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Comment: @JensSchauder As described above there is any stack trace. I’ll add the answer soon.

Comment: I added the answer. See below

Comment: Oh you are trying to say there is NO exception. Got it. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to the query itself. After reading Spring Data JPA doc I found this section:

> As the EntityManager might contain outdated entities after the execution of the modifying query, we do not automatically clear it (see the JavaDoc of EntityManager.clear() for details), since this effectively drops all non-flushed changes still pending in the EntityManager. If you wish the EntityManager to be cleared automatically, you can set the @Modifying annotation’s clearAutomatically attribute to true.

So I modified my update method like this:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query( value = "update payment pay set pay.amount_received = pay.amount_received + ?2 where pay.id = (select p.id from cart c inner join payment p on c.payment_id = p.id where c.product_id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true )
int updateAmountReceived( String idProduct, int amount );
```

That seems working.